# python classes methods of methods

Tags: python, methods, attributes, hierarchy

since I am pretty new to python I might be asking an obvious or silly question, but I really want to learn that concept.

```
class Classname:
     def method_1(self):
        ........
      ...................



instance = Classname()

instance.method_1.method_of_1.method_n
```

My questions is if this syntax implies the `method_1` , `method_of_1` and `method_n` are indeed methods or attributes of `Classname`. If they are methods shouldn't they be invoked as `instance.method_1().method_of_1().method_n()`.
The reason I am asking this is because this syntax is frequently seen in e.g. Matplotlib, where you have `ax.yaxis.set_ticks()`. Does this last example mean that we are accessing an attribute of `ax` called `yaxis`, and then call a method `set_ticks()`. So the syntax implies: `classname.attribute.method`.
How do you build such hierarchy? Can you direct me to the write place to read? I'd do it my self but don't know what exactly I am looking. I read about classes but haven't seen anything with two or more 'dots' e.g, `classname.attribute.method`.

Comment: In your example, `yaxis` is likely an instance variable, not a method.

Comment: Everything is an object, and you can defined whatever attributes you want on those objects. A method is simply an attribute that is a function, so it is callable, i.e. the call operator works `my_function_attribute()` where `()` is calling.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with `Matplotlib`, but it's possible to have sub classes like so:

```
class Foo():
    a = 1
    class Bar():
        b = 2
        def hello():
             print('world')
```

where you can invoke `Foo.Bar.hello()` and it'll print "world".

This can go on ad infinitum.  Since Python is object based it doesn't necessarily follow a set structure.

Comment: How do you pass a method(function) as argument from `Foo` to `Bar`. That is `def method_Foo ........return somtehing_Foo:` inside the Foo class, I want to be able to do `Foo.method_Foo.method_Bar().`

Comment: You can't.  A method/function doesn't have attributes/classes inside that you can reference to.  If you tried it will give you an `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method_name'`.